# Check variable is either array of custom type or array of arrays of that type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am chunking an array into smaller pieces if the original is longer than a specified amount, and I am wanting to perform a different action depending on if it is a 1D or 2D array.

```
type MyType = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

const performChunking = (arr: MyType[], CHUNK_MAX: number): MyType[] | MyType[][] => {
    if (!(arr.length > CHUNK_MAX)) return arr;

    let chunkedArray: MyType[][];
    // Perform chunking
    return chunkedArray;
}

const values: MyType[] | MyType[][] = performChunking(someArr, 5);

/*
    Here I want to perform something like

    if (typeof values === MyType[][]) {
        // return something;
    }

    // return something else
*/
```

I have looked at `instanceOf` but that doesn't accept arrays it seems.

Answer (score 2):

First, TypeScript types do not exist at runtime. They are [*erased*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) during compilation. Therefore runtime checks like `if (typeof values === MyType[][])` are not possible.

One way to ensure that a variable is of some specific type is by using a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). In the example below I checked whether the first item in `MyType[]` is an array. If so, we know we're dealing with a nested array of type `MyType[][]`.

There's just one problem: `[]` is assignable to `MyType[][]` as well. So you might want to change the type of the nested array to something like `[MyType[], ...MyType[][]]`. That ensures an array contains at least one item.

```
type MyType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

const performChunking = (
  arr: MyType[],
  CHUNK_MAX: number,
): MyType[] | [MyType[], ...MyType[][]] => {
  if (!(arr.length > CHUNK_MAX)) return arr;

  const chunkedArray: [MyType[], ...MyType[][]] = [[{ id: "", name: "" }]];
  // Perform chunking
  return chunkedArray;
};

declare const someArr: MyType[];
const values: MyType[] | [MyType[], ...MyType[][]] = performChunking(
  someArr,
  5,
);

function is2dArray(
  arr: MyType[] | [MyType[], ...MyType[][]],
): arr is [MyType[], ...MyType[][]] {
  return Array.isArray(arr[0]);
}

if (is2dArray(values)) {
  values;
  //^? const values: [MyType[], ...MyType[][]]
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUoEsAmAXFAM7ABOOAdgOYDcWUlAhgLYRGkU30C+9GAYwD2lUlEhkAZkLIsAwgAsArpQDWValFQAKBkzJkicRJADaAXQA0DOQAkAqgDkA0gH0YAQQAaRSkpYARhBk1gCURghIFlAAPlCmxlFWUAB0aYlm5hbmWgB86Aw4klDaAITa+mQpADYQNMAKUPl2Tm6eXqGhUGQQwEpklFCV-NjCosBQAspqEHgeBkwgRAmRmZap6asQFtla8aZouIRQAEQn68xsRGdQPObm9NgA9E9QAArB0rKT0+o0DD0+gMfipVLN5mRFrx+HgIAJqvpoGMxMQhGwIRETNsHoIRGIAG5MapKCDETFJWLxDLY9ZpFLUnb3PYSL7yX4aXTYVHogzWbAAVjC-EkKgEwBwIlwxAATHMFiBOUMDOTMpSVliLLTNhqsvcwkRKlKqVtNRt6SbdTlMNhAf1BhDFikcMQHQrKqYAAzmUK8DAYIolZ2y13aQnE0mdArYMMk4iPKAvAB6AH4MDwMEA)